# Least rank of a matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a $7\times 7$ matrix such that it has rank $3$ and $a$ be $7\times 1$ column vector.  Then least possible rank of $A+(a a^T)$ is? ($a^T$ is transpose of the vector)

Intuitively I think it's $2$ as $a a^T$ has rank $1$, and the most it could affect is one row of $A$.

Comment: For an introduction to posting with [math notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), see that portion of the site FAQ and its links to other resources about `MathJax` and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: While not literally the case that $aa^T$ can only affect one row of $A$, it is a good special case to motivate your intuition.  **Hint:** Consider left multiplying $A+aa^T$ by an invertible matrix which reduces the general case to the single row affected case of your intuition.

Answer (score 1):

your intuition is right. instead of working with rows as suggested by hardmath,  i will work with the columns of $A.$ without loss of generality, we can assume that the first three columns $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$ are linearly independent.the column space of $Aa + aa^\top$ is $\{Ax + aa^\top x = Ax + (a^\top x)\, a\     \}$
the dimension space is two iff there is an $x$ such that $a_1x_j + (a^\top x) a = 0,\  j = 1, 2, 3.$ in other cases the dimension is either three or four.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on the last part of the question, where you state that "the dimension space is two iff there is an $x$
 such that $$a_1x_j+(a^⊤x)a=0, j=1,2,3$$